# Sqlalchemy relationship: Order children by joined table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following relationship: a `course` has many `course_instances` and each `course_instance` belongs to a `semester`.

Here's a greatly simplified set of models:

```
class Course(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "courses"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    course_instances = relationship("CourseInstance", back_populates="course")


class CourseInstance(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "course_instances"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    course_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("courses.id"))
    semester_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("semesters.id"))

    course = relationship("Course", back_populates="course_instances")
    semester = relationship("Semester", back_populates="course_instances")


class Semester(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "semesters"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sort_ix = Column(Integer)

    course_instances = relationship("CourseInstance", back_populates="semester")
```

I often when to query for a course and include all of instances with `joinedload/contains_eager/selectinload`. These instances should always be sorted by the `sort_ix` column of each instance's semester.

Is there any way to specify this default ordering on the Course-model level? Something like this:

```
course_instances = relationship(
    "CourseInstance",
    back_populates="course",
    order_by="CourseInstance.semester.sort_ix"
)
```

The only thing I can think of is adding a duplicate column to `CourseInstance` like `semester_sort_ix`.

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569448/sqlalchemy-order-by-a-relationship-field-in-a-relationship but it has a bounty so it can't be closed.

Comment: You're right. Not sure why I couldn't find that issue when I searched. I answered my own question since I can't close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of a dup of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569448/sqlalchemy-order-by-a-relationship-field-in-a-relationship) with a different set of relationships. Here is the solution:

```
class CourseInstance(db.Model):
    semester_sort_ix = deferred(select([Semester.sort_ix]).where(Semester.id == semester_id))


class Course(db.Model):
    course_instances = relationship(
        "CourseInstance", back_populates="course", order_by="desc(CourseInstance.semester_sort_ix)",
    )
```